# AngularJS - hide <select> element if ng-option is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to hide the `<select>` element if the `ng-options` variables are empty after using a filter?

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="selected" 
        ng-options="property.pstSnr.description for property in leistobToProperties | filter: {grouping:1}">
</select>
```

The `<select>` element should not be visible if all the options of `property.pstSnr.description` are empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your filtered list and then use it in an `ng-show`:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-show="filteredSet" 
        ng-model="selected"
        ng-options="property.pstSnr.description for property in filteredSet = (leistobToProperties | filter: filtering)">
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjtLx8j4/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-show="filtered.pstSnr.description.length > 0" ng-options="property.pstSnr.description for property in filtered = (leistobToProperties | filter: {grouping:1})"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a select as well hidden if there are no options

```
<select id="categorylist" focus-on="focusMe" ng-change="UpdateDowntimeEvent()" class="col-md-11" name="CategoryId" ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName group by downtimeCategory.Node  for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories" required="" ng-hide="Model.DowntimeCategories ==0" >
```

You can try this

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="property.pstSnr.description for property in leistobToProperties | filter: {grouping:1}" ng-hide=" property.leistobToProperties == 0"></select>
```